# how can I make the getFilter function in an adapter to be recognized in a searchview querytextlistner?

Tags: kotlin, filter, android-recyclerview, adapter

I am working with kotlin searchview to filter a recyclerview, I literally copied the code from 3 people and it didn't work, the probleme is that it doesn't recognise the getFilter() function when I use it

- https://github.com/danielnimafa/android-search-recyclerview/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/danielnimafa/androidsearchrecyclerview/ContactsAdapter.kt
- https://github.com/teguholica/AndroidRecyclerViewSearchFilterSample/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/teguholica/androidrecyclerviewsearchfilter/MainActivity.kt
- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sJ-Z9G0SDhc   (this one is a javacode one but i converted it)

and this is my github repo : https://github.com/KhaldiAbderraouf/manazildz

```
override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu?): Boolean {
        var inflater : MenuInflater = getMenuInflater()
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu)

        var searchItem : MenuItem = menu!!.findItem(R.id.action_search)
        val searchManager = getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE) as SearchManager
        val searchView = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search).actionView as SearchView
        searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager.getSearchableInfo(componentName))
        searchView.maxWidth = Int.MAX_VALUE

        searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(object: SearchView.OnQueryTextListener{
            override fun onQueryTextSubmit(query: String?): Boolean {
        // here is the probleme :
                Annonce_Adapter.getFilter().filter(query)
                return true
            }

            override fun onQueryTextChange(newText: String?): Boolean {
                TODO("not implemented") //To change body of created functions use File | Settings | File Templates.
            }

        } )

        return true
    }
```

Comment: If you can debug the code, can you check if `onQueryTextSubmit` is getting called? If yes, then after that, result of the `filter` method should be added as a list in your recycler view adapter. and do share the rest of the code for better diagnosis.

Comment: I couldn't debug anything with that unresolved probleme. but for my code , checkout my github repo (4th link in my question)